# How to set up correctly openldap subordination?

Tags: openldap

I can't get to make this configuration work as expected:

```
# Database LDAP for ldap1
database        ldap
suffix          "ou=ldap1,dc=local"
uri ldap://ldap1
idassert-bind bindmethod=simple
   binddn="cn=admin,dc=ext1"
   credentials="secret3"
   mode=none
   flags=non-prescriptive
idassert-authzFrom "dn.exact:cn=manager,dc=local"
overlay rwm
rwm-suffixmassage   "ou=ldap1,dc=local" "dc=ext1"
subordinate

# Database LDAP for ldap2
database        ldap
suffix          "ou=ldap2,dc=local"
uri  ldap://ldap2
idassert-bind bindmethod=simple
  binddn="cn=admin,dc=ext2"
  credentials="secret2"
  mode=none
  flags=non-prescriptive
idassert-authzFrom "dn.exact:cn=manager,dc=local"
overlay rwm
rwm-suffixmassage   "ou=ldap2,dc=local" "dc=ext2"
subordinate

# Database LDAP for local Manager authentication
database ldap
readonly                yes
suffix "dc=local"
rootdn "cn=manager,dc=local"
rootpw secret1
```

Knowing that in ldap2, there's an entry for "cn=test", I'm only wanting that querying the master LDAP server (with base: "dc=local) would work, so basically, I'm looking to make this work:

```
 ldapsearch -x -b "dc=local" -D "cn=manager,dc=local" cn=test -H ldap://localhost -w secret1
```

Actually this query will stall...

Of course, querying the subordinate with base "ou=ldap2,dc=local" works flawlessly and return the correct entry. This is the query that works:

```
 ldapsearch -x -b "ou=ldap2,dc=local" -D "cn=manager,dc=local" cn=test -H ldap://localhost -w secret1
```

What is my mistake ? I'd like to glue both server to effectively search between both ldap1 and ldap2 servers with one request on the master.

Answer (score 1):

What was missing for the subtree search to work with `dc=local` base is the actual root object in the database for `dc=local`.

So I had to switch to `mdb` for the main database on suffic `dc=local` to have a dummy database where I could actually add new objects.

I had also to remove the `readonly  yes` statement of course.

And then I prepared this `base.ldif` file and added it to the base database:

```
cat <'EOF' > /tmp/base.ldif
dn: dc=local
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: Local
dc: local
EOF
ldapadd -h ldap://MYMASTERHOST -D cn=manager,dc=local -w secret1 -f /tmp/base.ldif
```

Then, both `ldapsearch` on the base `dc=local` and on subtree `ou=ldap2,dc=local` where working as expected.

I didn't forget to put back the `readonly yes` statement as I don't need to store anything in the master database.